# dojo: instantiate an object within its own class

Tags: javascript, dojo

Suppose I have a class (let's say, LinkedListNode.js) defined below:

```
// LinkedListNode.js
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare"
] , function (declare) {

    return declare(null, {

        constructor: function(data) {
            this._data = data;
        },

        addNext: function(data) {

        }

    });

});
```

How can I instantiate an instance of this class within its own definition, like below:

```
// LinkedListNode.js
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare"
] , function (declare) {

    return declare(null, {

        constructor: function(data) {
            this._data = data;
        },

        addNext: function(data) {
            this._next = new LinkedListNode(data);
        }

    });

});
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do in Java:

```
class LinkedListNode {
    private int data;
    private LinkedListNode next;

    public LinkedListNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void addNext(int data) {

        // How can I execute this same statement in JavaScript/Dojo?
        this.next = new LinkedListNode(data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do it like that in Dojo. You just put your new class in the define section of the place you want to use it and Dojo makes the instatiation for you. So if you saved on Object.js, you would use it like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "yourpath/Object"
] , function (declare, object) {

    return declare(null, {

        constructor: function() {
        },

        test: function() {
            object.whatever();
        }


    });

});
```

**Complemented based on edits**

Well to use the way you want, you can't do it with dojo's declare system. You have to do it in the more traditional way. Js is a free free language, you can do things in many ways. So you have several methods to do something like that in JS. Here are 3:

```js
function LinkedListNode(data) {
    this.addNext = function(data) {
        this.next = new LinkedListNode(data);
        return this.next;
    }
    
    this.data = data;
}

var ll1 = new LinkedListNode(777);
ll1.addNext(555).addNext(333);

console.log(ll1.next.data);
console.log(ll1.next.next.data);

function LinkedListNodeV2(data) {
    var self = {}
  
    self.addNext = function(data) {
        self.next = new LinkedListNodeV2(data);
        return self.next;
    }
    
    self.data = data;
    return self
}

var ll2 = LinkedListNodeV2(777);
ll2.addNext(555).addNext(333);

console.log(ll2.next.data);
console.log(ll2.next.next.data);

class LinkedListNodeV3 {

    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

 addNext(data) {
        this.next = new LinkedListNodeV3(data);
        return this.next;
    }
}

var ll3 = new LinkedListNodeV3(777);
ll3.addNext(555).addNext(333);

console.log(ll3.next.data);
console.log(ll3.next.next.data);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s1pemgbk/2/

But how do you put that in Dojo ? as allways in JS there are many ways, one of them is this:

```
// LinkedListHelper.js
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare"
] , function (declare) {

    class LinkedListNode {

        constructor(data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        addNext(data) {
            this.next = new LinkedListNode(data);
            return this.next;
        }
    };

    var self = {};

    self.getLLInstance = function(data) {
        return new LinkedListNode(data);
    }

    return self;
});
```

then you would use it like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    'project/helpers/linkedListHelper',
], function (
    declare,
    linkedListHelper
) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        postCreate: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);

            var ll = linkedListHelper.getLLInstance(777);
            ll.addNext(555).addNext(333);
            console.log(ll.next.data);
            console.log(ll.next.next.data);

        }
    });
});
```

Hope it's clearer now :)

Comment: Hi, I think you code assume `object` is a single tone. I think OP is interesting in creating an object instance from a dojo class.

Comment: @GibboK neither of these two answers is what I am looking for...see my edits

Comment: @scottyseus thanks for you comment, could you add more details in your question... where do you want initiate new Object(); in another class?

Comment: I am trying to instantiate a new Object within its _own_ class definition

Comment: I added some Java code that does exactly what I need as a reference

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this example, two dojo classes are created using dojo module `declare`. Dojo abstracts classes similarly to Java.
When a class is defined using `define` you can initiate it in your code at will.

In this example `YourMainClass`'s `constructor` contains a reference to an instance of `YourClass` were it was initiated.

Live demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/uw17etqg/

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang"], function(declare, lang) {
  var YourClass = declare(null, {
    constructor: function(name, age, residence) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.residence = residence;
    },
    print: function() {
      alert(this.name);
    }
  });
  var YourMainClass = declare(null, {
    constructor: function(name, age, residence) {
      this.yourClassInstance = new YourClass('foo', 'bar', 'zoo');
      this.yourClassInstance.print();
    }
  });
  var yourMainClass = new YourMainClass();
});
```